# ARIMA forecasts constrained to an interval in Python language

Tags: python, time-series, constraints, arima

I'm trying to copy the second exercise ("Forecasts constrained to an interval") in the link below:

https://otexts.com/fpp2/limits.html

What the link does is an ARIMA with forecasts constrained to an interval using a certain logarithmic transformation and then back-transformation at the end. But the example in the link uses R language, and I can't find a similar example for Python no matter how much I search.

Can anyone tell me how I can do the exact same thing described in the link with Python? I'm certain it is possible using the **statsmodels** library, but I'm not sure how to exactly replicate the transformation constraints.

The standard ARIMA in Python:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
import numpy as np 

model = ARIMA(series, order=(0,1,1))
model_fit = model.fit(trend='nc',full_output=True, disp=1)
print(model_fit.summary())
```

I have a feeling that I need to add something like this somewhere (transformation formula):

```
series = np.log((series-a)/(b-series))
```

as well as the back-transformation formula. But since they don't produce explicit errors I can't be sure whether I'm coding it right.

Also, I'm stuck at where I should be adding the transformation and back-transformation. I would appreciate it if someone could explain how the exercise in the link could be replicated in Python.

P.S. By 'transformation' here, it has nothing to do with making the time series stationary. I didn't mention the stationary part because it's unrelated to my current question. The link above uses the word 'transformation' to use the logarithmic formula to make the time series constrained to lie between 'a' and 'b'.

What I tried so far:

```
series = np.log((series-a)/(b-series))

model = ARIMA(series, order=(0,1,1))
model_fit = model.fit(trend='c',full_output=True, disp=1)
print(model_fit.summary())

fore = model_fit.forecast(steps=1)

fore = (b-a)*np.exp(fore)/(1+np.exp(fore)) + a
```

Comment: "Also, I'm stuck at where I should be adding the transformation and back-transformation" you mean making time series stationary by "transformation"?

Comment: No I mean making the time series constrained to lie between 'a' and 'b'. The link I posted describes this as 'transformation'. I'm not talking about making the series stationary. I'll clarify it in the post, but this can be understood more clearly when you read what's in the link.

Comment: I got your point.

Answer (score 2):

it's so clear from the link that you referred to in the question that the transformation is going to take place just before forecasting. so:

1. you do the transformation on your data
2. forecast using ARIMA model on transformed data
3. reverse the transformation on predicted data!

```py
a = 50
b = 400

# Transformation on the data
train = np.log((series-a)/(b-series))

# Choose suitable order
model = ARIMA(train,order=(2,2,2))
results = model.fit()

start=len(train)

# One step ahead forecasting. You should set value of the end to what you prefer
predictions = results.predict(start = start , end = 1 , dynamic=False , typ='levels')

# reverse transformation
predictions = ((b-a)*np.exp(predictions)/(1+np.exp(predictions))) + a
```

- Passing `dynamic=False` means that forecasts at each point are generated using the full history up to that point (all lagged values).
- Passing `typ='levels'` predicts the levels of the original endogenous variables. If we'd used the
  default `typ='linear'` we would have seen linear predictions in terms of the differenced
  endogenous variables.

Comment: Would this be right? This is what I tried so far: 
`series = np.log((series-a)/(b-series))

model = ARIMA(series, order=(0,1,1))
model_fit = model.fit(trend='c',full_output=True, disp=1)
print(model_fit.summary())

fore = model_fit.forecast(steps=1)

fore = (b-a)*np.exp(fore)/(1+np.exp(fore)) + a`

Comment: @Robin311 I'll make an exact example and implementation in python. I'm writing. the answer will be updated with Python codes.

Comment: Oh ok! Thank you so much :) I'll refer to the code you update.

Comment: Using your code (without any changes) produces an error which says, `Prediction must have "end" after "start"`. Do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: What's the version of `statsmodels` in your environment?

Comment: And can you please put a download link to the dataset? I want to test it by myself, so it would be much easier to catch up with the solution.

Comment: Oh, I fixed the problem, apparently the end value is supposed to be bigger than the start value. And the time series data was just created randomly using numpy (no real dataset).

Comment: Seem's you're using newer version of `statsmodels`. Good to hear that. You mean `end` should be `end=len(start)+1`.

Comment: Yes! I think that's correct :)